# Preprogrammed parallelism in OpenCV

Tags: multithreading, image-processing, parallel-processing, opencv3.0

I known that OpenCV has parallelism capabilities in the form of multithreading. For instance the forEach construct allows to accelerate loops, using NumThreads threads.

What is unclear to me is if some of the compute intensive functions (say FFT) are implemented as parallelized versions. I am not considering GPU acceleration here.

Do you have more info ?

Comment: Like you, I find the support/communication/documentation of OpenCV lacking in many respects and the lack of definitive answers about how it works quite frustrating - most people seem to *"muddle through"* after trying a few ideas. One option may be to try using **OPENCV_TRACE**, so you would run your application with `OPENCV_TRACE=1 ./YourProgram` and you get some trace files called `OpenCV*txt` and you can analyse them with `opencv/modules/ts/misc/trace_profiler.py` and see if there are any insights as to the number of threads...

Comment: ...further https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Profiling-OpenCV-Applications

Comment: I tried the OPENCV_TRACE trick (you can set it in a configuration file), but didn't get any log file.

Comment: Oh, it worked fine for me on macOS. I didn't even change my compilation commands, it seems to be switchable at run-time. Sorry, I don't know more than that - it's another thing no-one seems too sure about. In fact, I can't even find a question on StackOverflow with `OPENCV_TRACE` in it!

Answer (score 0):

Opencv is a complex library developed for years and it integrates most form of parallelism of present computers. This includes SIMD processing (for different processor vendors and different architecture generations), the use acellerators with CUDA, opencl or opengl and multithreading

Concerning the latter, opencv can use different frameworks depending on their availability (some are third party software, or are only available in some specific systems). This includes openMP, intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB), pthreads and proprietary frameworks on macOS and windows.

Though, I cannot say, if a given opencv function on your computer is parallelized. Not all functions are programmed with parallel support and parallel features must be explicitly selected at compile time. But opencv libs are frequently built with open-MP support for multithreading.

Comment: Is there a better way to know than digging the source code ?

Comment: Concerning the openmp support, it depends on the way you compiled the library. Most precompiled libs are built with openmp support on. Concerning specific functions, you need to dig the source. But I think many functions are parallelized with a minimal openmp support.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal openmp support" ? In particular, I target the functions `dft` and `filter2D`.

Comment: By adding a `#pragma mp parallel for` before your loops, you can have a decent parallelization of your code. That's what I call a minimal openmp support. Full optimization may require a larger code rewrite and it is probably less frequent. I haven't specifically looked at these functions. dft and FIR filters are easy to parallelize. But IIR filters have many dependencies and it is more difficult to have an efficient parallelization.

Comment: For the last time, my question is if there are pre-parallelized functions. I know how to parallelize code explicitly, but in my context this is not an option.

Comment: The answer is yes. Most opencv functions are parallelized and dft and filter_2D are commonly used modules. But I do not know if the parallelization is always really optimized, nor if 100% of the functions in these modules have parallel support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to digging the source code.

For example cv::dft function containt several implementation:

1. OpenCL on GPU, CPU or iGPU (you can set target device). It will be parallel on CPU also. You need to configure OpenCV build with OpenCL support, set use OpenCL true and set target device CPU (or another).
2. IPP implementation if your OpenCV build was configured with IPP in CMake.
3. [HAL implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d6/d77/structcv_1_1hal_1_1DFT2D.html) - also in CMake.
4. A simple OcvDftImpl.

All in your hands!